# Is there a way to add a Gridview footer as a single cell?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Everything I've looked at adds a column footer rather than a full row control footer. I want the Grid to render the footer as a single

```
<tr><td> <asp:somecontrol /> </td></tr>
```

row in the browser. I looked at abusing the Pager row, but it is even less customizable.

Comment: <td colspan="5"> <asp:somecontrol/> </td> (or however many columns the table contains)? or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done easily in the RowDataBound event.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //check if the row is a footer row
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        //span the first cell with the number of columns
        e.Row.Cells[0].ColumnSpan = e.Row.Cells.Count;

        //hide all other columns
        for (int i = 1; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[i].Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

The first TemplateField then can be used to hold the Control.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("myColumn") %>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Footer"></asp:Label>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Hmmm, that might work better than my solution. I also added the button via code, but it doesn't fire the RowCommand event.